# Применение корутин

Tags: python, сервер, concurrency

Корутины есть во многих языках программирования, но специфика их применения для меня весьма расплывчата. После [прочтения этого документа](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf) сложилось впечатление, что они используются только как фильтры для обработки данных и в задачах, где нужно переключение контекста (concurrency).

В общем, я запутался. Так что вопросы:

**1)** Какие еще есть применения у корутин?

**2)** Если использовать корутины при написании сервера, то как это должно работать? *(То есть понятно, что при поступлении запроса, его нужно обработать с помощью переключения контекста. Но ведь это один поток, и запросам нужно будет вставать в очередь, т.е. все будет тормозить).*

Comment: так презенташка хорошая, в неё достаточно просто всё написано и даже с всякими игрушечными примерами.

конкретно по поводу п.2 вопроса: можно, например, запустить количество процессов равное количеству ядер/потоков процессора и в каждом процессе обрабатывать поступающие запросы "корутиной"

ну и google://async web server architecture

Comment: Там примеры, которые я выше привел. А вообще было бы интересно узнать, где их еще можно применять.
По поводу второго вопроса: а эти процессы между собой не будут как-то конфликтовать? Правильно, ли я понял, что программа слушает порт, а потом уже пускает процессы для обработки? P.S. В гугле все больше с кэллбэками попадаются(тот же Twisted).

Comment: @Zamony а что такое "переключение контекста"?

Comment: Через yield, сохраняя внутреннее состояние функции, добровольно передать управление другой.

Comment: >>а эти процессы между собой не будут как-то конфликтовать?

ну так принимать запросы-то может всего один процесс и передавать другим на дальнейшую обработку. можно просто проксю какию-нибудь перед этим поставить, а твою программу просто запустить на разных портах


но, повторюсь, если тебе просто надо поковыряться в таком коде, чтобы понять асинк, сделай простенький примерчик. мне гевент более простым кажется.

Comment: @actionless, про второй вопрос вроде бы теперь примерно понятно. Но у меня только академический интерес, поэтому использовать Gevent(т.к. там все уже готово) неинтересно. К тому же он там с памятью вроде бы как-то химичит, чтобы можно было выполнять как async что угодно.
Но первый вопрос все еще открыт.